# Set nil string pointer to empty string

Tags: string, pointers, go

How do I set the referenced value of a string pointer in a type to the empty string?
Consider this example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Test struct {
    value *string
}

func main() {
    t := Test{nil}
    if t.value == nil {
        // I want to set the pointer's value to the empty string here
    }

    fmt.Println(t.value)
}
```

I've tried all combinations of the `&` and `*` operators to no avail:

```
t.value = &""
t.value = *""
&t.value = ""
*t.value = ""
```

Obviously some of those are silly, but I didn't see the harm in trying. 
I also tried using `reflect` and `SetString`:

```
reflect.ValueOf(t.value).SetString("")
```

and this gives a compilation error

> panic: reflect: reflect.Value.SetString using unaddressable value

I'm assuming that's because strings in Go are immutable?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

String literals are not [addressable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators).

Take the address of variable containing the empty string:

```
s := ""
t.value = &s
```

or use new:

```
t.value = new(string)
```