# Go json, marshal empty value

Tags: json, go, isnullorempty

I'm having problems with `omitempty` and empty values. Please see [this playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/0BLHQVcE3M). I have a value which I don't want to be ignored during marshal in case of value `""`. This explicitly means that I want to clear the value and therefore I want to have marshalled result:

```
{"cf_objectType":"Product","cf_isLocked":"No","cf_ErrorMessage":""}
```

Now I tried the pointer-to-string approach [here](https://play.golang.org/p/XIXrpcaDyw), but for some reason I don't like this. Are there any alternatives known? For example, why don't we have a tag (just like `omitempty`) like `omitnull` or something?

**EDIT**

To clarify, see below

```
m := Metadata{
    ObjectType:   "Product",
    Locked:       "No",
    ErrorMessage: "",

}
```

I want the result of the marshal function on this struct to be:

```
{
    "cf_objectType":"Product",
    "cf_isLocked":"No",
    "cf_ErrorMessage":""
}
```

**AND**

```
m := Metadata{
    ObjectType:   "Product",
    Locked:       "No",
}
```

result shoulde be:

```
{
    "cf_objectType":"Product",
    "cf_isLocked":"No",
}
```

Comment: which json do you want to get as a result? if you delete `omitempty` for `ErrorMessage` you'll get: `{"cf_objectType":"Product","cf_isLocked":"No","cf_errorMessage":""}`

Is it what you need?

Comment: See me edit, which illustrates a bit more.

Comment: The problem is, `ErrorMessage` is implicitly initialized to its zero value, `""`. So the two examples are feeding *identical data* into `Marshal`, so they will *always* yield identical output. If you don't like using a `*string` (though you don't state why), then even if there were an `omitnil`, it wouldn't help - you can't have a nil string, only a nil pointer, so you would still need to use a pointer to a string.

Comment: Ok, this works: https://play.golang.org/p/TYk67p6i_b
But then I have a mix of `string` and `*string` in my struct definition. And I also can't "fill" the value without having the `var emptyString = ""`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to your last comment (for which I don't have enough reputation to reply to):

> Ok, this works: [play.golang.org/p/TYk67p6i_b](http://[play.golang.org/p/TYk67p6i_b) But then I have a mix of
>   string and *string in my struct definition. And I also can't "fill"
>   the value without having the `var emptyString = ""`, right?

See [this (Golang: set nil string pointer to empty string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359812/golang-set-nil-string-pointer-to-empty-string#44359942) post

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to omit empty values, just remove `omitempty` tag

https://play.golang.org/p/6axA2OIG6O